# Making a polymer component that can listen to all key-presses on a page

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way for a Polymer 1.0 component to register for all of the key presses that occur on a page not matter where the focus is?

In a pre-components world I'd hook into the key events on the document body. What is the clean, component driven approach to this?

Comment: There's the iron-a11y-keys component.

Comment: You still have to add key events on `document.body` to achieve what you describe.

Comment: The demo for 'iron-a11y-keys-behavior' sets document.body as the keyEventTarget https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=IronA11yKeysBehavior  Unfortunately, I'm trying to implement this and despite trying to copy that demo, my elements have only themselves as targets. I can change the target to document.body in the console and my handlers fire. So close!

Comment: ah, i was boneheaded. got it!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by implementing the [`Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior` behavior](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=IronA11yKeysBehavior).

I basically just read the source to the component defined for that demo, which [is here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/blob/master/demo/x-key-aware.html)

The error I referred to in my comment to the original question was just me bone-headedly putting `keyEventTarget` in a `properties` object a screen or two above the `properties` object I'd already put in the page, which took precedence.

Here's a dead-simple component which shows it in action:

```
<dom-module id="x-component">
<template>
Type shift+a to see feedback.
<div id="feedback"></div>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-component',
    behaviors: [Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior],
    keyBindings: {
      'shift+a': '_handleKey'
    },
    _handleKey: function(e) {
      this.$['feedback'].innerHTML = this.$['feedback'].innerHTML + "<p>again</p>";
    },
    properties: {
      keyEventTarget: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return document.body;
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```